# yii2 dataprovider get all filtered data

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

I have grid view of student table when I filter table, for that instant I can get filter data by giving following

```
$allData=$dataProvider->getModels();
```

This $allData contains filtered data.
If I have 50 records, when I filter them I get 30 records, but this $allData shows only 20 records due to pagination limit 20.
so How do I get all my 30 filtered records into a variable as well as pagination?
if I set pagination size =0, then I will get all data, but I want pagination too.

So, how do I solve this?

Comment: Use `$allData=$dataProvider->query->all();`

Comment: it works,thanks for saved my day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If youre using `DataProvider`, you have `$query` as well. So using:

```
$models = $query->all();
```

will return all filtered models, and `DataProvider` will still have pagination.

Comment: it works, but syntax will be $dataProvider->query->all()

Comment: Propably youre passing `$query` to `$dataProvider` earlier, so you have `$query`, but both usages are correct.

Comment: I tried your codes, says $query is undefined. coz I was doing it in the controller, oh I should have used in a Search Model

Comment: Well, it should be in model, and i was guessing youre doing it there ;)